# PHP open graph facebook comments return array empty

Tags: php, facebook, comments

Because this work

https://graph.facebook.com/comments/?ids=http://www.nadvoe.org.ua/stud.my/post/49/

and this not work ??

https://graph.facebook.com/comments/?ids=http://www.kylie.com.br/primeiras-fotos-da-embalagem-do-dvd-aphrodite-les-folies/

the array is empty

Comment: Not quite sure what you are asking?

Answer (score 2):

I suspect this is a bug in FB's Graph API, and you should report it to Facebook.

I can clearly see that [the FB comments plugin](https://www.facebook.com/plugins/comments.php?api_key=157435107682068&channel_url=https%3A%2F%2Fs-static.ak.fbcdn.net%2Fconnect%2Fxd_proxy.php%3Fversion%3D3%23cb%3Df11b57d37%26origin%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Fwww.kylie.com.br%252Ff34d8f096%26relation%3Dparent.parent%26transport%3Dpostmessage&href=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fplugins%2Fcomments_v1.php%3Fapp_id%3D157435107682068%26xid%3D_post9867%26url%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Fwww.kylie.com.br%252Fprimeiras-fotos-da-embalagem-do-dvd-aphrodite-les-folies%252F&locale=pt_BR&migrated=1&numposts=10&publish_feed=true&sdk=joey&title=Primeiras%20fotos%20da%20embalagem%20do%20DVD%20Aphrodite%20Les%20Folies%20%7C%20KYLIE.com.br%20%E2%80%93%20Kylie%20Minogue%20Brasil&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.kylie.com.br%2Fprimeiras-fotos-da-embalagem-do-dvd-aphrodite-les-folies%2F&width=560&xid=_post9867) renders the 14 comments, but the [Graph API](https://graph.facebook.com/comments/?ids=http://www.kylie.com.br/primeiras-fotos-da-embalagem-do-dvd-aphrodite-les-folies/) returns none of the data.